# How to write Elasticsearch query into elasticsearch-dsl in python

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I'm trying to write a query to Elasticsearch using the elasticsearch-dsl library in Python 3.7.

I think I managed to write most of it but I'm having an issue with an "exist" clause.

This is the query I want to translate:

```
            {
                "query": {
                    "constant_score": {
                        "filter": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": { 
                                    "term": { "locale": "$locale" }
                                },
                                "must_not": {
                                    "term": { "blacklist_country": "$country_code" }
                                },
                                "should": [
                                { "term": { "whitelist_country": "$country_code" } },
                                { "bool": {
                                    "must_not": {
                                        "exists": { "field": "whitelist_country" }
                                    }
                                }}
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

And this is what I have so far:

```
q = Q('constant_score',
            filter={Q('bool',
                must=[Q('term', locale=locale)],
                must_not=[Q('term', blacklist_country=country_code)],
                should=[Q('term', whitelist_country=country_code),
                        Q('bool',
                            must_not=[Q('exists', field='whitelist_country')]
                        )
                       ]
                    )}
            )
```

I expect the query to run properly but I am getting currently this error:

```
...
must_not=[Q('exists', field='whitelist_country')]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Bool'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue, I solved it like this:

```
search = Search(using=client_es, index="articles") \
            .query('constant_score', filter=Q('bool',
                must=Q('term', locale=locale),
                must_not=Q('term', blacklist_country=country_code),
                should=[Q('term', whitelist_country=country_code),
                        Q('bool',
                            must_not=Q('exists', field='whitelist_country')
                        )
                       ]
                    ))
```